# data not saved in database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I just start learning rails so please be tolerant.
I have a form that create advices. An advice has a name, a content and belongs to a category.
When I try to create a new advice, the "name" and "content" datas are saved in database but not the category_id. I don't know what's missing to do it.

Note that I have run rails g scaffold Advice including "name" and "content" and then I added a collection_select in the form to select the category. Maybe the problem is here.

View :

```
<%= form_for(@advice) do |f| %>
  <% if @advice.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@advice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this advice from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @advice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Controller :

```
class AdvicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_advice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /advices
  # GET /advices.json
  def index
    @advices = Advice.all
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /advices/1
  # GET /advices/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /advices/new
  def new
    @categories = Category.all
    @advice = Advice.new
  end

  # GET /advices/1/edit
  def edit
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # POST /advices
  # POST /advices.json
  def create
    @categories = Category.all
    @advice = Advice.new(advice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @advice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @advice, notice: 'Advice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @advice }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @advice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /advices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /advices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @advice.update(advice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @advice, notice: 'Advice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @advice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @advice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /advices/1
  # DELETE /advices/1.json
  def destroy
    @advice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to advices_url, notice: 'Advice was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_advice
      @advice = Advice.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def advice_params
      params.require(:advice).permit(:name, :content)
    end
end
```

Schema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160316111225) do

  create_table "advices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :advices
  root 'advices#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the controller. You are not permitting the `category_id` in the strong parameters.

```
def advice_params
  params.require(:advice).permit(:name, :content)
end
```

should be:

```
def advice_params
  params.require(:advice).permit(:name, :content, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt see your answer there, i just deleted mine as yours was here first and was pretty well the same answer. my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use options_for_select in this situation:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.choices) %>
```

In your category model:

```
def self.choices
  cat_arr = []
  Category.find_each do |cat|
     cat_arr << [cat.name, cat.id]
  end
  cat_arr
end
```

passing it a two dimensional array will show the user names to select from but will save the integer id like you want.